# I have latitude and longitude separate fields without any wrapper(like location), how do I define "geo_point" data type

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-2.0

I am using **Elasticsearch 2.3.3**

I have `latitude` and `longitude` separate fields without any wrapper (like location), how do I define `geo_point` data type.

Here is my Document `JSON`:

```
{
 "app_id": "5647",
 "contacts": [
      {
         "first_name": "Sabir",
         "last_name": "Iqbal"
      }
    ],
   "latitude": 44.669365,  
   "longitude": -73.44533
}
```

Here is my Index settings and mappings.

```
 {
  "settings": {
    "number_of_shards": 1,
    "number_of_replicas": 1
  },
  "mappings": {
    "myType": {
      "properties": {
               "app_id": { "type": "string" },
              // want to define "geo_point" for latitude and longitude fields  ???
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Please help me out to define `geo_point`.